# What does CC sealing her code mean?

Tags: code-geass

So I understand that CC sealed her code to prevent Charles from obtaining it from her. It seems like she lost her memories due to that. My question now is: How exactly does this process work? If not for Marianne, was there a way for her to unseal this again? Was she mortal when the code was sealed, or was she still immortal and really confused?